# add a stylesheet to a JS

Tags: javascript, stylesheet

I want to add my own font style to the following JS script - how do I this?

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#contact').validate({
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                    url: 'process.php',
                    success: function () {
                        $('#contact').hide();
                        $('#contact-form').append("<p class='thanks'>Thanks! Your request has been sent.</p>")
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to apply some css rules to your `thanks` class? Do you have access to the stylesheet?

Comment: The title of your question doesn't match the rest of it. Adding a style sheet is something different than changing the font of an element.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LeMFz/

Answer (score 1):

Just add it straight to that tag if you're just trying to change the font of the 'thanks' class.

```
$('#contact-form').append("<p class='thanks' style='font-family: yourFont'>Thanks! Your request has been sent.</p>")
```

Comment: I thought the script was provided with the style 'thanks', but unable to locate that anywhere in my files which I found to be odd. I will try adding the previous code - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to add stylesheet to your head section

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

In stylesheet

```
.thanks {
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better set the font in class style through css file.In your css file:

```
.yourFontClass{
    font-family:Arial;
}
```

your success callback：

```
 $('#contact-form').append("<p class='thanks yourFontClass'>Thanks! Your request has been sent.</p>")
```

Hope it's useful for u. : )